# ValidationMessage asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a question about ModelState.AddModelError method and about the ValidationMessage method.

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and I am a little confused.

I wrote this code:

```
public ActionResult update(FormCollection collection)
{
    int oos = 0;

    try
    {
        oos = int.Parse(collection[0]);
    }
    catch
    {         
    }

    data d = new data();

    TryUpdateModel(d , collection.ToValueProvider());

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    { 
         return View("index",d);
    }
    else
    {      
        ModelState.AddModelError("Date", "Wronge Date");   
        d.Id = 50;
        return View("index",d);
    }
}
```

and this code in the view side

```
@{

    ViewBag.Title = "index";
}

<h2>index</h2>
@TempData["Hi"]

@Html.ValidationMessage("fullname") 

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{ 
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken() @Html.TextBox("id", 70) 
    @Html.TextBox("Date", "3/2/1991 12:00:00 ص")
    @Html.ValidationMessage("Date","Please insert the correct Date Format") 

    <input type="submit"> 
}
```

My questions are,  why the message *Please insert the correct Date Format* appears directly when I rune the index while still I did not submit the form, why when I submit the form with error in the date format,the same message appear but not the message that I set to the Date Key in the update method which is *Wronge Date*.

maybe still I do not understand those two methods so I hope to find somebody to explain them to me.

explnation with example or reference would be appreciated

Comment: Have you even declared the model in your view (`@model yourAssembly.data`)? Why are you using `FormCollection` instead of posting your model? And use the strongly typed helpers - `@Html.TextBoxFor(m -> m.Date)` and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m -> m.Date)`

Comment: If you post the model that will more helpful for us to know what kind of Message or validation you have set to your `Date` key!!

Answer (score 2):

Please look at http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation

Because you have already entered a message in the View it will use that over your error that you are adding from the controller. As for your fullname you do not have a message set yet, only the placehoder for the field.